# class method access

Tags: c++, embedded

Can someone explain me the diference in this two declarations ?

```
// Call super class method
This->objClass->super->OnConnect( (BasicIoControlType*)This );

// Call super class method
ClipListIoCtrlClassDef.super->OnConnect( (BasicIoControlType*)this );
```

Comment: You'll probably have to edit your question to provide some more details, such as relevant parts of the class declarations in question. As it stands, those two calls appear to do quite different things.

Comment: It's unlikely these are declrations.

Comment: As VJo implies, this doesn't look quite like C++. C++ is case sensitive, so you need `This` to look like `this` instead. `super` is a keyword in some languages, but not in C++ (doesn't really work with multiple inheritance). As such, unless it's defined in the class, it wouldn't work either.

Comment: Hi Greg, 
Thank you for replying.
The class definition is supossed to be hidden in the framework.
As I said i am newbie in OO language and this seemed to be just a mather of accessing the methods inside the classes.
I'd like to know the diferences of uses.

Comment: Class definitions are not "hidden" in C++, since the compiler has to be able to see them to compile your code. You will probably find the declaration in a `.h` file in a framework include directory. Since Google has [exactly one hit for `ClipListIoCtrlClassDef`](http://www.google.com/search?q=ClipListIoCtrlClassDef) (this very question), I must conclude that the framework you're working with is an internal framework of some kind rather than something that's commonly used. Perhaps you should investigate internal training resources?

Comment: It is either not C++ or there's a good amount of magic going on (`super` being an attribute that points to the base subobject? `This` being a pointer to an object?)

Comment: @Jerry, this can still be valid C++. `This` is most likely some sort of pointer field, maybe pointing to some sort of meta object providing pseudo-reflection support. Probably. It is hard to deduce more meaningful info from these two snippets.

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov: It *can* be valid C++, but as I said, doesn't really look like it. I'd consider it unlikely (and if they enough other "stuff" there to make it valid C++, we're going to need a fair amount of context to sort out what's going on).

Comment: It looks like someone is trying to emulate C++ using C. This and super are probably variable names in C, not keywords. The [embedded] tag also hints at C. I've seen this sort of thing before. I still don't get what the question is, though.

Answer (score 1):

Code given in question:

```
// Call super class method
This->objClass->super->OnConnect( (BasicIoControlType*)This );

// Call super class method
ClipListIoCtrlClassDef.super->OnConnect( (BasicIoControlType*)this );
```

This *can* in principle be C++, but it sure doesn't look like C++.

It it is C++, then there's no difference in the calls other than the specification of the object to call `OnConnect` on.

In the first case, *if* this is C++, you probably have a pointer `This` that points to an object with a member `objClass`, which is a pointer to an object with a member `super`, which points to an object with a method `OnConnect`. I have to write "probably" because C++ allows overloading of the `->` operator, which means that those beasties are not necessarily raw pointers. *If* this is C++.

In the second case, *if* this is C++, you have an object `ClipListIoCtrlClassDef` that has a member `super` that (probably) is a pointer to an object with an `OnConnect` method. Again I have to write "probably" because C++ allows `->` to be overloaded. And you don't provide the necessary context.

It *may* be that you're wondering about the difference between `o.method()` and `p->method()`.

If so, the built-in `->` is just a shorthand for writing `(*p).method()`, where `*` is the pointer dereferencing operator. If this is unfamiliar to you, consult your C++ textbook. And if you don't have a textbook: you need one (e.g., Bjarne Stroustrup's latest).

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I suspect that the `This` in the question should really be `this`.

Comment: Thanks Alf,
It helps a lot.
I cannot assure this is a C++ code.
To explain better: It is a part of code that I am working on. It is intended to run in a microcontroller. The guys that have done the code used some OO concepts and sometimes I get lost in the code.

Comment: Thanks Alf,
It helps a lot.
I cannot assure this is a C++ code.
To explain better: It is a part of code that I am working on. It is intended to run in a microcontroller. The guys that have done the code used some OO concepts and sometimes I get lost in the code.
Maybe this part of code can help:
--
void ClipListIoCtrl_OnConnect(ClipListIoCtrlType *this)
{
    ClipListIoCtrlClassDef.super->OnConnect( (BasicIoControlType*)this );
--
void CallIoCtrl_OnConnect(CallIoCtrlType *This)
{
    This->objClass->super->OnConnect( (BasicIoControlType*)This );
--
It seems that this is just a pointer != This